# Many to many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

Hello I am having a hard time debugging my code. What I need to do is create a page where the user will type in a last name and the system will return information related to it. I am stuck and can not debug it any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Model of my Customer table

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :booking
  has_many :room, :through => :booking 

 def mail_list
    "#{first} - #{last} - #{maillist}"
  end
end
```

Here is the page that should display the data after the user enters a last name

```
<center><table width = 65% border = 1> 
     <tr> <th> Customer Name</th><th> Room Number </th>  <th> Cost </th></tr>   
   <% @customers_list.each do |m| %>
   <% p = m.cost %>

        <tr> <td> <%= m.name %> </td> <td> <%= m.roomnumber %> </td> <td> <%= m.cost %> </td> </tr> 
      <% end %> </table> </center><br /> <br />
```

Here is the page that takes in the last name

```
<%= form_tag(bookin_bookout_path, :controller => "bookin", :action => "bookout", :method => "post") do %>

  <div class="field">

         <%= label_tag :Customer_Name %><br />

         <%= text_field_tag :customer_name_in %>
  </div>



      <div class="actions">

          <%= submit_tag "Submit Customer Name" %>
  </div>

   <% end %>
```

Model of my rates table

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :season, :room, :cost, presence: true 

has_many :booking
  has_many :room, :through => :booking

end
```

Here is the Controller of my bookin that runs the user putting in last name and posting results

```
class BookinController < ApplicationController

def bookin


  def bookout
  @customer_name = params[:customer_name_in]
   r = Customer.find_by_last(@customer_name)
   @room_list = r.rooms
  end
end
end
```

Here is the Model of my room table

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :booking
has_many :customer, :through => :booking

end
```

Here is the Model of my booking table

```
 belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :rate

end
```

Here is my routes

```
Hotel::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :bookings

  get "bookin/bookout"
  post "bookin/bookout"
  get "listin/listout"
  resources :customers

  get "manin/manout"
  resources :users

  get "mailin/mailout"
  get "showin/showout"
  resources :roomins

  get "ratein/rateout"
  get "foodin/foodout"
  resources :apples

  resources :rooms

  resources :menus

  resources :rates

  get "starter/home"
  resources :foods

  get "bookin/bookname"
  post "bookin/bookname"





   root 'starter#home'

end
```

Comment: Firstly change your associations,it is `has_many :bookings` not `has_many :booking` I suggest you to read these Guides first http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: And also you are confused with `Model` and `Controller` terms. You are referring a controller which is actually a model.

Comment: my apologies yes I am referring to the model for room, rate, customer, booking

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `pluralized` model name with `has_many`, use this

```
has_many :bookings
has_many :rooms, :through => :bookings
```

You have not followed rails' [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) in naming your models and controllers

Comment: Hello I have fixed the issue of pluralization and I still receive the error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass